# JavaScript ES6 get sum of values being mapped in array in the same loop iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have a unique challenge that I have been trying to solve. I have an object like this:

```
    obj = 
    [
      {item: "Skirt", price: 290}, 
      {item: "Shoes", price: 300}, 
      {item: "Skirt", price: 450}, {item: "Jeans", price: 35}
    ]
```

I am mapping this to get count of duplicate items with their respective average price, so that the desired output looks like:

**UPDATE:**

```
obj = 
[
 {
 Skirt: 2, 
 price: 370, //2 being the count of skirt items, 370 average price
 Jeans: 1, 
 Price: 35, 
 Shoes: 1, 
 Price: 30
 }
]
```

I am using this function to map the items:

```
Av_price = function(values) {
    let new_val = new Map();
       for (let x of values)
         new_val.set([x["item"]],  [(new_val.get(x["item"])|| 0) +1), (new_val.get(x["price"] || x["price"])/x["price"]])
return [...new_val.entries()];
};
```

The problem here is: I am able to count the number of items, say skirts, but unable to get the second value straight, I mean the prices; so that I can divide them by total number of items (which, in this example, are "2" for skirts, for example)! 
This unique challenge has boggled my mind for two weeks. Is there any way to get the count of all the skirt being mapped in the same loop iteration and then divide the sum of prices by their count to get an average price?

I will be hugely thankful for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a hash table for same items and build the average out of the stored values.

```js
var data = [{ item: "Skirt", price: 290 }, { item: "Shoes", price: 300 }, { item: "Skirt", price: 450 }, { item: "Jeans", price: 35 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    var ref;
    if (!hash[o.item]) {
        hash[o.item] = [{ item: o.item }, [0, 0]]
        result.push(hash[o.item]);
    }
    ref = hash[o.item][1];
    ref[1] = (ref[0] * ref[1] + o.price) / ++ref[0];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With a changed data structure for the result, you yould omit the hash table and take the result object directly.

```js
var data = [{ item: "Skirt", price: 290 }, { item: "Shoes", price: 300 }, { item: "Skirt", price: 450 }, { item: "Jeans", price: 35 }],
    result = data.reduce(function (o, { item, price }) {
        o[item] = o[item] || 0;
        o[item + 'Price'] = (o[item] * (o[item + 'Price'] || 0) + price) / ++o[item];
        return o;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think your answer is providing the complete solution including the average, but is it possible to do it in a structure like @Jared Smith did? Thank you for that.

Comment: I have updated the desired structure. Can you please look into that now?

Answer (score 1):

```
let totalItems = obj.reduce((acc, {name, price}) => {
  if (!acc[name]) {
    acc[name] = 0;
    acc[`${name}Price`] = price;
  }
  acc[name] += 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

now you have the price of each item and the total number of each. The `totalItems` object will look something like this:

```
{
  skirt: 6,
  skirtPrice: 290,
  shoes: 3,
  shoesPrice: 300
}
```

and so on.

Comment: I like this answer because of its simplicity. Wish it worked. In the result array it says "undefined"

Comment: This is how I am implementing it in the function: 
`Av_price = function(obj) {
    let totalItems = obj.reduce((acc, {brand, sale_price}) => {
  if (!acc[brand]) {
    acc[brand] = 0;
    acc[`${brand}Price`] = sale_price;
  }
  acc[brand] += 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
};`

Comment: @Zafar you're not returning `totalItems`, so of course the return value is going to be undefined. Instead of `let totalItems = obj.reduce...` just `return obj.reduce...`.

Comment: @Zafar, if you need a different result structure, you better ask the structure in your question. a comment in an answer does not help.

Comment: Bang, that's a beautiful answer. Yes I was not running it actually. I returned it now. @JaredSmith Thanks alot

Comment: you're right. Next time I will clearly define the structure too. Your answer too is correct, thank you so much.@NinaScholz

Comment: Wait, I think its not averaging the price, is it? @JaredSmith

Comment: @Zafar correct, I missed that requirement. Go with NinaScholz's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Array#reduce to create the map, which will contain the `count` and the summed price for each item. Then spread the map to entries, and Array#map it to the requested format:

```js
const arr = [
  {item: "Skirt", price: 290}, 
  {item: "Shoes", price: 300}, 
  {item: "Skirt", price: 450}, 
  {item: "Jeans", price: 35}
];

const Av_price = (values) => [...
  new Map(values.reduce((map, { item, price }) => {
    const o = map.get(item) || { sum: 0, count: 0 };
    o.count++;
    o.sum += price;

    return map.set(item, o);
  }, new Map()))
].map(([item, { count, sum }]) => [item, [count, sum/count]]);

const result = Av_price(arr);

console.log(result);
```